# Is there a word that means "connected to a conversation, being able to hear, etc."?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word that means "connected to a conversation, being able to hear, read or any similar phrase" for "video conversation, chat, phone conversation"? I am trying to think and I can't find a very idiomatic way of saying this. Could you also provide with an example sentence, or a few of them? "Be on the line" can be used for phone conversation, but what about other form of communication like radio, video chat, etc?

For example:

> Don't talk bad about him, he's still ___.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no best way to convey this meaning. You can use:

> - ... he's still **around**
> - ... he's still **close**
> - ... he's still **listening**
> - ... he's still **in the listening range**
> - ... he can still **hear us / read the messages / in front of the screen**
> - ... he's still **with us** (this has the second meaning of "he's still alive")

Answer (score 0):

At work where we constantly use online conferencing services we often say

> - ... he's still **dialed in**
> - ... he's still **in the call**
> - ... he's still **online**
> - ... he's still **joined**
> - ... he's still **there, but on mute.**
>
> Last one, which is particular (at least for me) to written language online forums, where people read along without posting:
>
> - ... he's still **lurking** (Noun: **a lurker**)

Disclaimer: Most of them derived from some of the often heard computer announcements that are part of our conferencing solution, where you are regularly given instructions on how to **dial in** or are given audio notifications like *Peter has joined the meeting.*

Language background: I'm German, and our conferencing mostly happens with non-native English-speaking colleagues from Spain, Germany, China and a lot of native English speakers from India.